# org.gradle.internal.component.AmbiguousVariantSelectionException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After using gradle project as library in my android studio project I get the AmbiguousVariantSelectionException exceptions

This is the entire log file, I've named the library module libraryy

> org.gradle.internal.component.AmbiguousVariantSelectionException: More than one variant of project :libraryy matches the consumer attributes:
>     - Configuration ':libraryy:debugApiElements' variant android-aidl:
>         - Found artifactType 'android-aidl' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
>         - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>     - Configuration ':libraryy:debugApiElements' variant android-classes:
>         - Found artifactType 'android-classes' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
>         - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>     - Configuration ':libraryy:debugApiElements' variant android-manifest:
>         - Found artifactType 'android-manifest' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
>         - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>     - Configuration ':libraryy:debugApiElements' variant android-renderscript:
>         - Found artifactType 'android-renderscript' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
>         - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>     - Configuration ':libraryy:debugApiElements' variant jar:
>         - Found artifactType 'jar' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
>         - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultArtifactTransforms$AttributeMatchingVariantSelector.doSelect(DefaultArtifactTransforms.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultArtifactTransforms$AttributeMatchingVariantSelector.select(DefaultArtifactTransforms.java:89)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet.select(DefaultArtifactSet.java:126)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultVisitedArtifactResults.select(DefaultVisitedArtifactResults.java:48)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.select(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:112)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.select(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.getResolvedArtifacts(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:78)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getResolvedArtifacts(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:296)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor226.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:64)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
>       at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$_failOnVersionConflictForGroup_closure13.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:399)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor222.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
>       at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
>       at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$CompositeSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:196)
>       at org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet.execute(MutableActionSet.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:204)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:198)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.java:79)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:132)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:760)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:746)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:666)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:135)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:249)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:167)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
>       at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
>       at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>       at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
>       at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

And the build.gradle script

> dependencies {
>       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>       androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
>           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
>       })
>       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
>       implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
>       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
>       implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
>       implementation 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'
>       implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
>       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
>       implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
>       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
>       implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
>       implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
>       implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
>       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
>       implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
>       implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3'
>       implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
>       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
>       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
>       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
>       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
>       implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'
>       implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.1.0'
>       implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'
>       implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
>       implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
>       //implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
>       implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
>       implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
>       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>       implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
>       implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
>       implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
>       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
>       implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
>       implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
>       //implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.4.0'
>       implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
>           transitive = true
>       }
>       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
>       implementation project(':libraryy')
>   }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, you have more then one module named libraryy with the two y's at the end.
Show a screenshot of your project's folder structure and post your `build.gradle` file and of course if you are using flavors show that as well.

But it seems you simply have more than one child module by this name.
In order to find all of your references you will need to

- Check your libs directories, make sure you don't have a lib there.
- Check your build.gradle for repeat dependencies as well as settings.gradle for repeat includes
- Check your transitive dependencies (aka your dependencies of your dependencies, you can check this by running gradle dependency command to review the tree
- Lastly, check that your cache isn't messed up. You can do this in two ways.

1) you can review the contents of your iml files and idea specific files to see if it got added twice, or 
2) you can simply delete all your "build" directories, and iml files and idea files. then reimport the project. You could also simply do File->Invalidate Cache and Restart to see if that resolves you.

Somewhere you have an extra pointer to this library, so start by checking those locations, if you don't find it still, then I would invalidate cache, and if that doesn't work then delete all the generated directories and import from gradle again, but I would be surprised if you don't find it in one of those places.